# How to retrieve a dropped table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I accidentally deleted a table called DEPARTMENT from my oracle database and I want to restore it back. So I googled and found the solution.

Here is what I did:

```
SHOW RECYCLEBIN;

CRIMINALS              BIN$hqnw1JViXO/gUwPAcgqn3A==$0 TABLE       2019-04-16:13:17:16 
DEPARTMENT             BIN$hqnw1JVjXO/gUwPAcgqn3A==$0 TABLE       2019-04-16:13:19:04 
DEPARTMENT             BIN$hqnw1JVkXO/gUwPAcgqn3A==$0 TABLE       2019-04-16:13:21:23 
DEPARTMENT             BIN$hqnw1JVnXO/gUwPAcgqn3A==$0 TABLE       2019-04-16:13:36:34 

FLASHBACK table department TO BEFORE DROP;
Flashback succeeded.
```

If you can see the SHOW RECYCLEBIN QUERY, You can tell there are more than one department table and all of them have different content. My Question is how can I get the content of all 3 table in one.

Answer (score 0):

After flashback, rename each `DEPARTMENT` table to a new name, e.g.

```
rename department to dept_1;
```

Do it for all of them but the last one (whose name will remain `DEPARTMENT`). Then insert the rest of data into it:

```
insert into department
  select * from dept_1
  union all
  select * from dept_2;
```

Note that uniqueness might be violated; if table's description has changed, `select *` might not work (so you'll have to name all columns, one-by-one).

But, generally speaking, that's the idea of how to do it.